# Mailcatcher Error: port 1025 is already in use

Tags: port, lsof, mailcatcher

I try to start mailcatcher. And I got error: something's use port 1025. Are you already running MailCatcher?

I try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35039407/mailcatcher-error-error-somethings-using-port-1025-are-you-already-runni/52058021#52058021%22this%22), and similar answers, but, when I execute lsof command, there is nothing in result for this command which use this port, result of lsof command is EMPTY.

Any idea? (I can't reach the 127.0.0.0:1080 or similar, and my command to start mailcatcher is $ mailcatcher -ip=0.0.0.0)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem. Restarting vagrant and restarting the computer did not help. I worked around it by starting mailcatcher using
`mailcatcher --foreground --http-ip=0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Thank you,  `$mailcatcher --foreground --http-ip=0.0.0.0 ` is solved my problem.